# checking for nil, still crashing saying its nil

Tags: swift, null, swift4

I have a condition as below.

```
var hotelType: String = "test"

hotelType==hotelInfo.type!
```

Let's say `hotelInfo` have struct as below.

```
struct HotelInfo : Decodable {
    var type: String?
}
```

As app was crashing saying that `hotelType` was nil, I update code as below.

```
hotelType==(hotelInfo.type!==nil ? "" : hotelInfo.type!)
```

However still app is crashing saying ***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

Is there way where I can check for nil before checking actual data.

**Note:**, *I have alternate solution (which is working fine also), but for sure I feel this is wrong. What I would be doing is adding another variable as making nil to blank string as below and check for this variable.*

```
struct HotelInfo : Decodable {
    var type: String?
    var typeFixed: String? {
        get {
            if (self.type==nil) {
                return ""
            }
            return self.type
        }
    }
}
```

& use this variable

```
hotelType==hotelInfo.typeFixed!
```

***Most Important***

I am doing this inside filter so I can't use `if let` statement (this is actual code, but I give above simple logic as data is very complex)

```
finalArray = finalArray.filter { hotels in
    hotels.infos?.contains { roomInfo in
        selectedChain.contains { rt in
            rt == (roomInfo.hotelChain?.supplierHotelChain!==nil ? "" : roomInfo.hotelChain?.supplierHotelChain!)
        }
        } ?? false
}
```

`rt == (roomInfo.hotelChain?.supplierHotelChain!==nil ? "" : roomInfo.hotelChain?.supplierHotelChain!)` this is where I am checking for condition.

Could someone point me in right direction to get desired data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will still crash because you are *force unwrapping* `hotelInfo.type` *before* checking if it is `nil`:

```
hotelType==(hotelInfo.type!==nil ? "" : hotelInfo.type!)
```

Had you done:

```
hotelType == (hotelInfo.type == nil ? "" : hotelTypeInfo.type!)
```

it would have worked.

Instead, use the [nil coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

```
hotelType == (hotelInfo.type ?? "")
```

---

In your filter statement:

```
finalArray = finalArray.filter { hotels in
    hotels.infos?.contains { roomInfo in
        selectedChain.contains { rt in
            rt == (roomInfo.hotelChain?.supplierHotelChain ?? "")
        }
    } ?? false
}
```